# Python script works on one setup but fails to import module on another setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I have been searching the web from any direction to try and find a reasonable idea to why my problem happening.

**Important to say, the code is in a shared location that both machines can access with full permissions**
I'll take you through it but first I'll share the way my repo is built:

```
my_repo
├── installations
│   ├── my_install_script.py
├── topology
│   ├── common_topology.py
├── utils
│   ├── boot_utils.py
│   ├── other_utils.py
```

The flow is:

my_install_script.py is been called, imports boot_utils.py
then from within boot_utils.py I import 2 more modules like that:

```
from utils.other_utils import foo, goo, boo
import topology.common_topology as resources
```

My issue that I can't seems to put my finger on:

When running this from 1 machine, the my_install_script.py works great and runs till the end.
When running it from another machine, I am getting exceptions because python fails to import topology.common_topology with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'topology.common_topology'" Error.

I know, it makes no sense.

Even using sys.path.insert(0,path to my_repo) before the second import, it is still failing.

I've been trying using different sys.path.insert, but I don't get lucky to make this work.
But it should not take this effort since I've been using the same code just from 2 different machines

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in the topology subdirectory on one or both machines?

Comment: No, this is no `__init__.py` file at all, why?

Comment: The error message suggests that it did find a module named `topology`, but not a submodule named `common_topology`. Try this on both systems: `import topology` and then print these things: `topology.__file__`, `topology.__path__`, and `dir(topology)`. Perhaps you will see some difference in that output which explains things.

Comment: Adding an empty `__init__.py` to the subdirectory was solving this problem. I still do not understand how and why but it works great so far